# Rotate single chevron on accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want one chevron to rotate when you click the corresponding header. As of now all chevrons rotate. I figure I have to specify which chevron, but I don't know how. I am working in ASP.NET MVC 5 and I am using razor view to foreach through a list.

> Index

```
@{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="accordion">
            <a href="#"><h4>@item.Title</h4><i class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-desc">
            <h3>@Resource.AccordionProjectLead</h3>
            <h4>Kay Wiberg</h4>
            <h3>@Resource.AccordionDescription</h3>
            <p>
            @item.Description
            <p> 
            <div class ="link">
                <a href="@item.Url">@Resource.AccordionGoTo</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

> CSS for the rotating chevron

```
.rotate {
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
}

.rotate.down {
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

> JS for accordion and chevron

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".accordion-desc").fadeOut(0);
  $(".accordion").click(function() {
    $(".accordion-desc").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
    $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
  });
});

$(".accordion").click(function() {
  $(".rotate").toggleClass("down");
});
```

> from the browser:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="accordion">
    <a href="#">
      <h4>Test Site</h4><i class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate down"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-desc" style="display: none;">
    <h3>Projektledare</h3>
    <h4>Kay Wiberg</h4>
    <h3>Beskrivning</h3>
    <p>

    </p>      
    <div class="link">
      <a href="">Gå till</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion">
    <a href="#">
      <h4>Test site 2</h4><i class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-desc" style="display: none;">
    <h3>Projektledare</h3>
    <h4>Kay Wiberg</h4>
    <h3>Beskrivning</h3>
    <p>
      Somthindsyvgds
    </p>
    <div class="link">
      <a href="">Gå till</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `$(this).find(".rotate").toggleClass('down')`

Comment: Updated question with conent from browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".accordion-desc").fadeOut(0);
  $(".accordion").click(function() {
    $(".accordion-desc").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
    $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
  });
});

$(".accordion").click(function() {
  $(".accordion").not(this).find(".rotate").removeClass("down");
  $(this).find(".rotate").toggleClass("down");
});
```

```css
.rotate {
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
}

.rotate.down {
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.accordion {
background: blue;
}
.fa, h4 {
color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="accordion">
    <a href="#">
      <h4>Test Site</h4><i class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate down"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-desc" style="display: none;">
    <h3>Projektledare</h3>
    <h4>Kay Wiberg</h4>
    <h3>Beskrivning</h3>
    <p>

    </p>
    <div class="link">
      <a href="">Gå till</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion">
    <a href="#">
      <h4>Test site 2</h4><i class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-desc" style="display: none;">
    <h3>Projektledare</h3>
    <h4>Kay Wiberg</h4>
    <h3>Beskrivning</h3>
    <p>
      Somthindsyvgds
    </p>
    <div class="link">
      <a href="">Gå till</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It works, bur forgot to mention in my question that when I click another heading i want the chevron already facing down to turn up. How can I achive this?

Comment: Oh, another thing. Now when I click the same heading thats open the chevron dont go up again.

Comment: Made another adjustment and I've included a snippet.